# How to read json file in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to get object from `api.json` but it throws error , based on typescript i have added `declare module "*.json"` into the project , Any idea how can i achieve this task ?

api.json

```
{
  "Refills": {
    "getPatientInfo": "Refills/patientInfo/GetPatientInfo"
  }
}
```

index.ts

```
import {ModuleExecutor} from "./common/ModuleExecutor";
import {Identity} from "./common/Enums";
export class Index {

    private executor: ModuleExecutor = null;
    // Any string prepended with @ is handled by grunt before building the project
    // grunt dynamically reads the config/api.json and loads only the apis that are listed there
    // api.json consists of the API name and the folder path for grunt

    private _apisConfig: string = '@api'
    constructor(identity: string) {
        this.executor = new ModuleExecutor(Identity[identity]);
        const apiConfig = JSON.parse(this._apisConfig);
        console.log('API',  apiConfig);
        for (const module in apiConfig) {
            if (apiConfig.hasOwnProperty(module)) {
                this[module] = {};
                for (const api in apiConfig[module]) {
                    if (apiConfig[module].hasOwnProperty(api)) {
                        this[module][api] = this.executor.execute(apiConfig[module][api]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Compiled index.js file

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const ModuleExecutor_1 = require("./common/ModuleExecutor");
const Enums_1 = require("./common/Enums");
class Index {
    constructor(identity) {
        this.executor = null;
        this._apisConfig = '';
        this.executor = new ModuleExecutor_1.ModuleExecutor(Enums_1.Identity[identity]);
        const apiConfig = JSON.parse(this._apisConfig);
        console.log('API', apiConfig);
        for (const module in apiConfig) {
            if (apiConfig.hasOwnProperty(module)) {
                this[module] = {};
                for (const api in apiConfig[module]) {
                    if (apiConfig[module].hasOwnProperty(api)) {
                        this[module][api] = this.executor.execute(apiConfig[module][api]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
exports.Index = Index;
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

Comment: You may want to use tick marks (``) instead of single quote marks (`'`) around `@api`. Your JSON has multiple lines, so the parser stops at the first line break and throws the error.

Comment: So, the markdown parser is impossible :). `<tickmark>@api<tickmark>` :)

Comment: i tried that but it still throws same error, can you give me an example please ?

Comment: This would be easier if you could show the compiled JS file after grunt has run...

Comment: @Mike McCaughan added compiled file to the question

Comment: Well, there's nothing in the `_apisConfig` but an empty string, so that's why it's throwing an error.

Comment: thats what i am trying to do get json object but not sure how to do that with typescript

Comment: From [this article](https://hackernoon.com/import-json-into-typescript-8d465beded79) it looks like you have to put more than just `declare module "*.json";` in your typings.d.ts.

Comment: i have whole thing there `declare module "*.json" {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}`

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you're doing with the `@api` stuff and grunt. You should be able to do `import * as apiConfig from "./api.json`.